# Dual y-axis of probability histogram and cumulative probability across the histogram all in one plot

Tags: matplotlib, montecarlo

I have two functions.

1. The first generates does a monte carlo simulation of different risk scores using some user input.
2. The second function generates a histogram of the risk scores, then puts vertical markers at the 5% and 95% bin edges.  Finally, the cumulative probability is calculated across the histogram.
3. The result are a series of figures that should show the bin count on y-axis 1 and the cumulative sum on y-axis 2.

The code works BUT the cumulative sum on y-axis 2 is not scaled correctly in the plot.  Any pointers would be welcome.

The following is the code for the functions.  The resulting figure has the probability results WAY below 1.  I ran a function to check the results go from 0 to 1 (also below).

```
#dependencies
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#Reference: Stochastic Risk Analysis: Monte Carlo Simulation and FMEA (Failure Mode and Effect Analysis), 
#Revista Espacios, 2017, 38(4), 26- 

#Functions
#Program workflow:
#1. generate dataframe from failure modes (FM) their associated RPNs with 
# "generate_rpn_dataframe"
#2. generate histograms of FMs with 5% and 95% indicator lines with 
# "plot_histogram_with_percentiles".  Overlay the probability distribution.

#function for generating a panda df of RPN for different failure modes
def generate_rpn_dataframe(df):

    # Initialize an empty DataFrame to store the results
    result = pd.DataFrame()

    # Loop over the columns in the input DataFrame
    for col in df.columns:
        # Get the min, max, and average from the first three elements of the column
        min_val = df[col].iloc[0]
        avg_val = df[col].iloc[1]
        max_val = df[col].iloc[2]


        # Generate 5000 elements from a triangular distribution
        data = np.random.triangular(min_val, avg_val, max_val, 5000)

        # Add the data to the result DataFrame
        result[col] = data

    return result

def plot_histogram_with_percentiles(dataframe):
    """
    Generates histograms for each column in the input DataFrame and adds vertical red lines
    at the 5% and 95% bin edges. Displays histograms in rows of three.

    Args:
        dataframe (pd.DataFrame): Input DataFrame containing the data.

    Returns:
        None (Displays the plots directly).
    """
    # Initialize an empty DataFrame to store the results
    result = pd.DataFrame()
    
    # Calculate the percentiles
    q = [0.05, 0.95]
    percentiles = dataframe.quantile(q)

    # Determine the number of rows and columns for subplots
    num_columns = dataframe.shape[1]
    num_rows = (num_columns + 2) // 3  # Divide by 3 and round up

    # Create subplots
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=num_rows, ncols=3, figsize=(15, 5 * num_rows))

    for col_idx, column in enumerate(dataframe.columns):
        row, col = divmod(col_idx, 3)  # Calculate row and column indices for 
                                       # subplot
        ax = axes[row, col]
        column_data = dataframe[column]

        # Plot the histogram
        n, bins, patches = ax.hist(column_data, bins=50, color='skyblue', alpha=0.7, edgecolor='black')

        # Calculate cumulative probability across the histogram
        cumulative_sum = np.cumsum(n)/len(column_data)

        # Plot cumulative sum as a line plot
        ax.plot(bins[:-1], cumulative_sum, color='green', label='Cumulative Sum')

        # Add vertical red lines at the 5% and 95% bin edges
        for percentile in percentiles[column]:
            ax.axvline(percentile, color='red', linestyle='--', linewidth=2, label=f'{percentile:.2f}')

        ax.set_title(f'Histogram for {column}')
        ax.set_xlabel('RPN')
        ax.set_ylabel('Bin Count')
        ax.legend()

        #Second y-axis is the cumulative probability
        ax2 = ax.twinx()
        ax2.set_ylabel('Cumulative Probability')
    
        result[column] = cumulative_sum    #for testing

    # Hide any empty subplots
    for i in range(num_columns, num_rows * 3):
        fig.delaxes(axes.flatten()[i])

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

    return result

#example workflow
# 1. define the failure modes and the associated scores (values taken from ref)
rpn = {'fm1': pd.Series([1,12,60],
                        index=['min', 'avg', 'max']),
          'fm2': pd.Series([2,36,60],
                           index=['min', 'avg', 'max']),
          'fm3': pd.Series([6,45,60],
                           index=['min', 'avg', 'max']),
          'fm4': pd.Series([6,15,60],
                           index=['min', 'avg', 'max']),
          'fm5': pd.Series([4,45,60],
                           index=['min', 'avg', 'max']),
          'fm6': pd.Series([3,10,30],
                           index=['min', 'avg', 'max']),
          'fm7': pd.Series([18,75,100],
                           index=['min', 'avg', 'max'])}
df_rpn = pd.DataFrame(rpn)

# 2. Apply Monte Carlo Method to generate dataframe of FMEA scores
fmea_dist = generate_rpn_dataframe(df_rpn)

#3. Visualize histogram
hist_results = plot_histogram_with_percentiles(fmea_dist)


##checking to see that cumulative sums go from zero to one
def scatter_plots_for_columns(dataframe):
    """
    Generates scatter plots for each column in the input DataFrame and displays them in a single figure.

    Args:
        dataframe (pd.DataFrame): Input DataFrame containing the data.

    Returns:
        None (Displays the combined plot directly).
    """
    num_columns = dataframe.shape[1]
    num_rows = 1  # Display all scatter plots in a single row

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=num_rows, ncols=num_columns, figsize=(15, 5))

    for col_idx, column in enumerate(dataframe.columns):
        ax = axes[col_idx]
        column_data = dataframe[column]

        # Generate scatter plot
        ax.scatter(column_data.index, column_data, color='b', alpha=0.7, label=column)

        ax.set_title(f'Scatter Plot for {column}')
        ax.set_xlabel('Index')
        ax.set_ylabel('Probability')
        ax.legend()

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    
scatter_plots_for_columns(hist_results)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Found the error!  In the function "plot_histogram_with_percentiles(dataframe)" I had to set, and reference, the two axes appropriately (e.g. ax1 and ax2).

Answer (score 0):

The following is the corrected code for plot_histogram_with_percentiles(dataframe):

```
def plot_histogram_with_percentiles(dataframe):
"""
Generates histograms for each column in the input DataFrame and adds vertical red lines
at the 5% and 95% bin edges. Displays histograms in rows of three.

Args:
    dataframe (pd.DataFrame): Input DataFrame containing the data.

Returns:
    None (Displays the plots directly).
"""
# Initialize an empty DataFrame to store the results
result = pd.DataFrame()

# Calculate the percentiles
q = [0.05, 0.95]
percentiles = dataframe.quantile(q)

# Determine the number of rows and columns for subplots
num_columns = dataframe.shape[1]
num_rows = (num_columns + 2) // 3  # Divide by 3 and round up

# Create subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=num_rows, ncols=3, figsize=(15, 5 * num_rows))

for col_idx, column in enumerate(dataframe.columns):
    row, col = divmod(col_idx, 3)  # Calculate row and column indices
    ax1 = axes[row, col]
    column_data = dataframe[column]
    
    # Plot the histogram
    n, bins, patches = ax1.hist(column_data, bins=50, color='skyblue', alpha=0.7, edgecolor='black')
    
    # Calculate cumulative sum
    cumulative_sum = np.cumsum(n)/len(column_data)
    
    #Second axis is the cumulative probability
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    
    # Plot cumulative sum as a line plot
    ax2.plot(bins[:-1], cumulative_sum, color='green', label='Cumulative Sum')
    
    # Add vertical red lines at the 5% and 95% bin edges
    for percentile in percentiles[column]:
        ax1.axvline(percentile, color='red', linestyle='--', linewidth=2, label=f'{percentile:.2f}')

    ax1.set_title(f'Histogram with Cumulative Probability for {column}')
    ax1.set_xlabel('RPN')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Bin Count')
    ax1.legend()
    ax2.set_ylabel('Cumulative Probability')

    result[column] = cumulative_sum    #for testing

# Hide any empty subplots
for i in range(num_columns, num_rows * 3):
    fig.delaxes(axes.flatten()[i])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

return result
```